# Hack to unittest cmd module without returning string

Tags: python, unit-testing, cmd

So strange question, the cmd module breaks the cmdloop() (main sudo command line loop) whenever I return with a return message. With unittesting, the assertequal method only works with what is returned. How can I get around this?

## commandline.py

```
def do_cd(self, directory):  # change directory
    '''
    syntax 'cd [directory]'
    change to [directory]
    '''

    args = directory.split(' ')
    # next 6 lines are cheater proof biz
    if args[0] == 'game':
        self.stdout.write('\nnot a directory')
        return
    if os.path.split(os.getcwd())[1] == 'user' and args[0] == '..':
        self.stdout.write('\nnot a directory')
        return

    try:
        os.chdir(args[0])
    except OSError:
        self.stdout.write('\nnot a directory')
        return
```

## unittesting.py

```
...
def test_cd(self):
        self.assertEqual(CommandPrompt.HelloWorld().do_cd('foo'), '\nnot a directory')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of options spring to mind:

1. Return the string you write to stdout. You mentioned this breaks your main loop - this doesn't sound like desired functionality. Perhaps investigate why this is happening?
2. Use the [`pytest`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/contents.html) unit testing framework and it's builtin fixture [`capsys`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/capture.html).

   ```
   import pytest

   def test_cd(capsys):
       # given a non-existent dir
       # when try to cd to dir
       # then print error to stdout
       CommandPrompt.HelloWorld().do_cd('foo')
       out, err = capsys.readouterr()
       assert out == '\nnot a directory.'
       assert err == ''
   ```

Comment: I feel hesitant to use a non built in framework but I will keep an open mind. Also, I did try printing to stdout, but no luck

Comment: I was also kinda hesitant to start using it too, but really grew to appreciate how much more fun testing could be the more I used pytest. I think it's greatest advantage is how easy tests are to read above other frameworks, in particular unittest. Lot's of huge projects have switched from unittest/nose etc. to pytest too: Mozilla, scipy etc. Give it a shot. :) You can either directly write your tests with it, or just use it as a runner for unittest.